# Android JavaScript content click opens URL in same WebView

Tags: javascript, android, browser, hyperlink, webview

I want to open all URLs from my WebView in the default browser of an android device. For this I'm using a custom WebViewClient with it's *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* function overridden and loading a new Intent (it works fine). The problem is that I have some JavaScript content in my WebView and clicking that content opens the URL in a clear but same WebView. The question is: How can I force those URLs to open in the default browser?

Thanks.